# Extending a sequence statistically in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scripting

Is there any built-in functions in MATLAB that would statistically extend a sequence of real numbers so that the resulting sequence is extended to any size I want. I have a sequence of 499 elements and I want to extend it to 4096 elements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically extend"? Extend mantaining the same distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "statically extend a sequence"? Do you mean generate more terms of an arithmetic sequence, based on some number of initial terms that define the pattern?

Comment: Exactly...The data in the sequence represents a signal, so the added data must be statistically interpolated.

Comment: I need intermediate added data (data between points in the sequence)... I cannot add data and the end of the sequence.

Comment: There is no such thing as statistical interpolation. Interpolation will replicate the data points exactly, and allow you to insert new values that are intermediate to the old ones. If you wish to find a smooth curve that fits your data, and then interpolate using that curve, this is curvefitting, modeling, or smoothing. There are many tools to accomplish this. But you need to decide which problem you wish to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to interpolate a vector of 499 elements to a higher resolution of 4096 elements, you can use the [INTERP1](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html) function in the following way (where `x` is your 499-element vector):

```
y = interp1(x,linspace(1,499,4096));
```

The above uses the function [LINSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) to generate a 4096-element vector of values spaced linearly between 1 and 499, which is then used as the interpolation points. By default, the INTERP1 function uses linear interpolation to compute new values between the old points. You can use other interpolation methods in the following way:

```
y = interp1(x,linspace(1,499,4096),'spline');  %# Cubic spline method
y = interp1(x,linspace(1,499,4096),'pchip');   %# Piecewise cubic Hermite method
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the word "statistically" in the question, but from your comments it seems that you just need linear (or smooth) interpolation.
Try with [interp1q](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/interp1q.html) or [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the distribution of the data to be in a [Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution) or [Johnson](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generating-data-using-flexible-families-of-distributions.html) system of parametric family of distributions, then you can generate more data using the sampling functions [pearsrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pearsrnd.html) and [johnsrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/johnsrnd.html) (useful in generating random values without specifying which parametric distribution)

#### Example:

```
%# load data, lets say this is vector of 499 elements
data = load('data.dat');

%# generate more data using pearsrnd
moments = {mean(data),std(data),skewness(data),kurtosis(data)};
newData = pearsrnd(moments{:}, [4096-499 1]);

%# concat sequences
extendedData = [data; newData];

%# plot histograms (you may need to adjust the num of bins to see the similarity)
subplot(121), hist(data), xlabel('x'), ylabel('Frequency')
subplot(122), hist(extendedData), xlabel('x'), ylabel('Frequency')
```

or using johnsrnd:

```
%# generate more data using johnsrnd
quantiles = quantile(data, normcdf([-1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5]));
newData = johnsrnd(quantiles, [4096-499 1]);
```

On the other hand, if you want to assume a non-paramteric distribution, you can use the [ecdf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html) function or the [ksdensity](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) function.
Please refer to the demo *[Nonparametric Estimates of Cumulative Distribution Functions and Their Inverses](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/nonparametric-estimates-of-cumulative-distribution-functions-and-their-inverses.html)* for a complete example (highly suggested!).